# How do I stop mouse_out firing when mouse click fires

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, click, out

I have buttons that have mouse_over, mouse_out and CLICK events. But when I click the button it takes me to another frame and the mouse_out event tried to fire. How do I stop that happening?

```
act1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, act1Pressed);    
act1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, act1Over);
act1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, act1Out);
act1_btn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, act1EnterFrame);



function act1Over(e:MouseEvent):void 
 {
  trace("over");
  act1Animating = true; 
  logo_1.visible = true;
  bubble.visible = true;
  txt1.visible = true;
 }

 function act1Out(e:MouseEvent):void 
 {
  act1Animating = false;
  logo_1.visible = false;
  bubble.visible = false;
  txt1.visible = false;
 }

 function act1EnterFrame(e:Event):void
 {
  if (act1Animating && e.target.scaleY < 1.1)
  {
   e.target.scaleY += 0.02;
   e.target.scaleX += 0.02;

  } 

  if (!act1Animating && e.target.scaleY > 1)
  {
   e.target.scaleY -= 0.02;
   e.target.scaleX -= 0.02;
  } 
 }

 function act1Pressed(e:MouseEvent):void 
 {
  trace("clicked");
  act1Animating = false;
  logo_1.visible = false;
  bubble.visible = false;
  txt1.visible = false;
  gotoAndStop(2);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to handle this:

1) Only assign the MOUSE_OUT listener in the MOUSE_OVER handler, then remove it after the MOUSE_OUT handler is done.  I.e.,

```
function act1Over(e:MouseEvent):void {
  /* your code */
  act1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, act1Out); 
}

function act1Out(e:MouseEvent):void {
  /* your code */
  act1_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, act1Out); 
}
```

2) Use [stopPropagation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/index.html) in your CLICK handler:

```
function act1Pressed(e:MouseEvent):void {
  /* your code */
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Also, in the future, please use code tags to mark up your code!

Answer (score 2):

It might not be a bad idea to give ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT MouseEvent a shot instead. These just fire once when someone rolls over the object, or rolls out, instead of firing continuously.

Comment: ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT was what fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button , you will trigger a MouseOver & a MouseOut event , if you don't wish to trigger the MouseOut event after the Click event , then you should remove the MouseOut event listener in the Click event listener.

This means that in order to be sure that you have a MouseOut listener when you MouseOver , you should add your MouseOut listener in the MouseOver listener.

Finally, you should remove the MouseOut event listener within the MouseOut listener.